# What should i do, when user cant send message to twitter

Tags: ios, ios5, twitter

I got app, which can send twits.

I do it in this way:

```
- (IBAction)twitDream:(id)sender
{
    if ([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet]) {
        TWTweetComposeViewController *tweet = 
        [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
        if (dream.image != [UIImage imageNamed:@"blank-photo.png"])
        [tweet addImage:dream.image];
        NSString *twitMsg = [dreamField.text stringByAppendingString:@" send via Dreamer"];
        [tweet setInitialText:twitMsg];
        [self presentModalViewController:tweet animated:YES];
    } else {
        //can't tweet!
    }
}
```

What should i do when `[TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet]` is equal to `NO` ? And when it is equal to `NO` ?

Comment: this method returns according to the doc : YES if Twitter is accessible and at least one account is setup; otherwise, NO. You probably want to tell the user that Twitter isn't accessible, or ask him to log in

Comment: and which method help me log in user

Comment: i'm not a Twitter expert and I won't read the whole doc for you. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is full solution code:

```
- (IBAction)twitDream:(id)sender
{
    if ([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet]) {
        TWTweetComposeViewController *tweet = 
        [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
        if (dream.image != [UIImage imageNamed:@"blank-photo.png"]) {[tweet addImage:dream.image];}
        NSString *twitMsg = [dreamField.text stringByAppendingString:@" #Dreamer"];
        [tweet setInitialText:twitMsg];
        [self presentModalViewController:tweet animated:YES];
    } else {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                                  initWithTitle:@"Sorry"                                                             
                                  message:@"You can't send a tweet right now, make sure your device has an internet connection and you have at least one Twitter account setup"                                                          
                                  delegate:self                                              
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"                                                   
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
}
```